# FATAL master.HMaster: Unexpected state : .. Cannot transit it to OFFLINE

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I've got a serious Hbase crash problem. I'm using HBase 0.94.7 with one master and two region servers. The HBase master crashed regularly, I can't even get it restarted. I've got the master logs as following:

```
DEBUG master.AssignmentManager: Handling transition=RS_ZK_REGION_CLOSED, server=master,60020,1374506461230, region=46c2333f401964bf877254be19c2cc8c
DEBUG handler.ClosedRegionHandler: Handling CLOSED event for 6423df864603aa6e8c45c726ab3ae62f
DEBUG master.AssignmentManager: Forcing OFFLINE; was=LogDetail,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01?\xF8\xB3\x8F\x17\xCE\xE2g\x84,1374498065657.6423df864603aa6e8c45c726ab3ae62f. state=CLOSED, ts=1374508769672, server=slave,60020,1374506460892
DEBUG zookeeper.ZKAssign: master:60000-0x14006f52f3f000e Creating (or updating) unassigned node for 6423df864603aa6e8c45c726ab3ae62f with OFFLINE state
FATAL master.HMaster: Unexpected state : LogDetail,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01?\xF6\xC17p&c\x8F\x14,1374498085655.c2f4143750eb1559a1dd92e937ea712d. state=PENDING_OPEN, ts=1374508769697, server=master,60020,1374506461230 .. Cannot transit it to OFFLINE.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected state : LogDetail,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01?\xF6\xC17p&c\x8F\x14,1374498085655.c2f4143750eb1559a1dd92e937ea712d. state=PENDING_OPEN, ts=1374508769697, server=master,60020,1374506461230 .. Cannot transit it to OFFLINE.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.setOfflineInZooKeeper(AssignmentManager.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.assign(AssignmentManager.java:1394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.handler.ClosedRegionHandler.process(ClosedRegionHandler.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO master.HMaster: Aborting
DEBUG handler.ClosedRegionHandler: Handling CLOSED event for 0710b486dcb3d51465695b51db376255
```

....

```
DEBUG master.AssignmentManager: The znode of region LogDetail,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01?\xF6\xC17p&c\x8F\x14,1374498085655.c2f4143750eb1559a1dd92e937ea712d. has been deleted.
INFO master.AssignmentManager: The master has opened the region LogDetail,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01?\xF6\xC17p&c\x8F\x14,1374498085655.c2f4143750eb1559a1dd92e937ea712d. that was online on master,60020,1374506461230
DEBUG master.AssignmentManager: Handling transition=M_ZK_REGION_OFFLINE, server=master,60000,1374508461536, region=c9cfdd360c09b292412ba5ad88815e6f
DEBUG catalog.CatalogTracker: Stopping catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@5c061cd2
INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x14006f52f3f000f
INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14006f52f3f000f closed
INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
INFO master.AssignmentManager$TimerUpdater: master,60000,1374508461536.timerUpdater exiting
INFO master.SplitLogManager$TimeoutMonitor: master,60000,1374508461536.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor exiting
INFO master.AssignmentManager$TimeoutMonitor: master,60000,1374508461536.timeoutMonitor exiting
INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14006f52f3f000e closed
INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
INFO master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting
ERROR master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
```

I also found something unusual in the ZK log:

```
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /master:37856
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /master:37856
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x140100dda0300e1 with negotiated timeout 180000 for client /master:37856
WARN org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x140100dda0300e1, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:220)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /master:37856 which had sessionid 0x140100dda0300e1
```

Can anybody help to see what the problem is? Is it related to the unassigned region or something like this? I've tried the `bin/hbase hbck -repair` and  `bin/hbase hbck -fix`, but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: It might be related to the load balance as my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830668/hbase-region-over-region-servers-load-not-balanced). Once the load balance is off which means only one region server is really working, it will be fine.

Comment: Could you please show me your complete HM and ZK logs?Pastebin or something...

Comment: Here it is: [Hbase Master log](http://pastebin.com/hybyJFXu), [Hbase zookeeper log](http://pastebin.com/bFKVspJY). From the moment I turned on the balance switch until it shut down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checked the log of my region server very carefully, I got the answer.

**Cause**

It turns out that there is one library called 'SNAPPY' for the compression of the hbase table is not well installed on the region server. And all my tables are created using this compression algorithm. When the master tries to balance the region to the region server, it failed. Eventually the master aborted.

**Solution**

Install and configure the SNAPPY on **EVERY NODE** as following:

```
apt-get install libsnappy1
su hbase
mkdir /home/hbase/hbase-0.94.7/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
ln -s /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1.1.2 /home/hbase/hbase-0.94.7/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libsnappy.so
exit (-> root)
ln -s /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1.1.2 /usr/lib64/libsnappy.so.1.1.2
ln -s /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1.1.2 /usr/lib64/libsnappy.so.1
ln -s /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1.1.2 /usr/lib64/libsnappy.so
ln -s /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1 /usr/lib/libsnappy.so
```

Now everything is OK! The regions are well balanced over region servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the region server log, if it is caused by LZO compressor missing and you are using Cloudera Hadoop,you can install lzo easily according to the following instruction:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/v1/v1-0-1/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_lzo.html