# HBase region over region servers load not balanced

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm running a small cluster with two region servers of HBase 0.94.7. I find that the load request over region servers is very unbalanced. From the Web UI, I got:

```
Region1:  numberOfOnlineRegions=1, usedHeapMB=26, maxHeapMB=3983
Region2:  numberOfOnlineRegions=22, usedHeapMB=44, maxHeapMB=3983
```

The region2 is servered as master. I checked that the load balancer is on. And I find some logs in the master log:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Skipping load balancing because balanced cluster; servers=2 regions=1 average=0.5 mostloaded=1 leastloaded=0
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Balance parameter: numRegions=10, numServers=2, max=5, min=5
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Calculated a load balance in 12ms. Moving 5 regions off of 1 overloaded servers onto 1 less loaded servers
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Balance parameter: numRegions=8, numServers=2, max=4, min=4
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Calculated a load balance in 0ms. Moving 4 regions off of 1 overloaded servers onto 1 less loaded servers
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.LoadBalancer: Skipping load balancing because balanced cluster; servers=2 regions=1 average=0.5 mostloaded=1 leastloaded=0
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: balance hri=LogTable,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01@\x09\xB2\xBA4$\xC3Oe,1374591174086.65391b7a54e9c8e85a3d94bf7627fd20., src=region2,60020,1374587851008, dest=region1,60020,1374587851018
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager: Starting unassignment of region LogTable,\x00\x00\x01\xE8\x00\x00\x01@\x09\xB2\xBA4$\xC3Oe,1374591174086.65391b7a54e9c8e85a3d94bf7627fd20. (offlining)
```

It seems that the load cannot be balanced from the region2 to region1. I don't know if it's a configuration problem? What parameter should I check on region1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using sequential rowkeys, like timestamp?If that is the case you might end up with **RegionServer Hotspotting**, putting uneven load on the servers. Avoid using sequential keys, if you can. If it is not possible create pre-splitted tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My rowkey is composed of ID, a log date and a generated hash value. I'm not sure if it's the case of sequential rowkeys. If so, how can I create the pre-splitted table?

Comment: Are the IDs sequential?Have a look these links for pre-splitted tables : http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/RegionSplitter.html  and http://hbase.apache.org/book/perf.writing.html

Comment: The IDs are not sequential. It's rather like type of logs. Actually, I turned off the load balance now, because I find that once it's on, I have another serious problem posted here: [HMaster aborted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792619/fatal-master-hmaster-unexpected-state-cannot-transit-it-to-offline). Can you please have a look at this problem? It seems to me that the other region server is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

if your rowkey is composed of ID, a date and a hash value, you could make the rowkey :hashvalue+date.

Comment: Change the rowkey is not possible now. My real problem is actually another region server is not working properly see this post [HMaster aborted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792619/fatal-master-hmaster-unexpected-state-cannot-transit-it-to-offline)